# Get HTML textfield and use as variable in c# (cshtml)

Tags: c#, html, razor

I have this input in HTML

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="usernameField" id="username" runat="server">
```

I want to get the value of this `textfield` and use it in my `c#` method in `cshtml`, I know I cannot use the regular `document.getElementById`. I tried `HTML agility pack` but as far as I know it cannot be used for this. The purpose of this is, that I have two inputs, username and password, where the user types the login information, and it will compare the input values with the values in the database.

The location where I want to use the HTML element values is in the SQL statement, at username and password:

```
WHERE username = " + "'" + username + "'" + " AND password = " + "'" + password
```

This is the full `c# cshtml` method:

```
@using System;
@using Npgsql;
@using HtmlAgilityPack;
@functions{

    public Boolean ValidateLogin()
    {        

        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;User Id=postgres;
Password=postgres;Database=login;");
        // Open Database connection.
        conn.Open();

        // Define a query returning a single row result set.
        NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT username, password FROM logindata 
WHERE username = " + "'" + username + "'" + " AND password = " + "'" + password + "'" + ";", conn);

        // Execute the query and obtain a result set.
        NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

        // If result exists return true and gain access to the control website.
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            return true;
        }

        // Close Database connection.
        conn.Close();
        return false;
    }
}
```

More information:

- I am doing this in visual studio 2017
- I am using asp.net CORE
- I am using cshtml files (also called razor I believe)

Comment: Does the textfield have a ASP.NET name? Is it running on the server side?

Comment: No asp name, its just a normal textfield in HTML, it runs on client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technology you are using here is called Razor Pages which is a new feature of ASP.NET Core MVC that makes coding page-focused scenarios easier and more productive.([Razor Pages docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/))

If you're looking for information on how to use the Model-View-Controller approach, check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc).

For your problem you need a `Login.cshtml` and a `Login.cshtml.cs` file which will created for you automatically if your right-click on `pages` folder and select `Add` > `Razor Page...`.

These files should contain:

Login.cshtml

```
@page
@model WebApplication1.Pages.LoginModel

<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" asp-for="UserName">
    <input type="password" asp-for="Password">

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Login.cshtml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace WebApplication1.Pages
{
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public bool IsloggedIn { get; private set; }

        public void OnPost()
        {
            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;User Id=postgres; Password = postgres; Database = login; ");
            // Open Database connection.
            conn.Open();

            // Define a query returning a single row result set.
            NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT username, password FROM logindata WHERE username = @username AND password = @password", conn);

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", UserName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Password);

            // Execute the query and obtain a result set.
            NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

            // If result exists return true and gain access to the control website.
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                IsloggedIn = true;
            }

            // Close Database connection.
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I changed they way you use the `username` and `password` in your query to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have tried your code, and I do not get any errors, how can I test if it works? Can I return an alert or something to see if it worked?

Comment: shouldn't the OnPost method get called somewhere or shouldn't I put something at the button like "onclick"

Comment: @daddybig No, you don't need the `onclick`. After clicking the submit button the `OnPost` gets executed automatically and sets the `IsloggedIn` value. You can use it in the `cshtml` file and check if the user is already logged in or you can redirect him to another page. I suggest you read the docs a bit to get more familiarized with this stuff.

Comment: @daddybig  Stuff like user authentication is already implemented in ASP MVC and you can use them easily

Comment: I made the method OnPost return RedirectToPage("http://www.google.com"); but when I click the submit button the page updates and nothing happens

Comment: @daddybig If you change the `OnPost` return type to `IActionResult` you can redirect to an internal page with `return RedirectToPage("Index");` It won't work for external addresses like google.com

Comment: It still does the same, the submit button just refresh the page and nothing happens, i will see what i can do, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.